# Bugzilla can't install DBD::mysql

Tags: mysql, redhat, perl, bugzilla

Im not at all familiar with anything that I am doing right now... so I am extremely nervous about it.

I have some websites running on my server using mysql.

I use `mysql -v`
and I get:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I use `./checksetup --check-modules` as bugzilla documentation specifies.

I get the response that a number of modules need to be installed.

I have installed all these modules.

However when I try to install DBD::mysql I get an error.

```
/usr/bin/make --NOT OK
```

I have placed all the output into a text file, but did not want to post it here as it is very long.

Does anyone know how I can overcome this issue?

I am using Redhat Linux... and Im a NooB ;(

EDIT:
To run the mysql update I use this command:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DBD::mysql
```

With regards to running CPAN, I am not sure, but these lines are appear in the output

```
Checking for                 CPAN (v1.81)     ok: found v1.98
Checking for                 YAML (any)       ok: found v0.81
Checking for   ExtUtils-MakeMaker (v6.31)     ok: found v6.62
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.15)
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:27:03 GMT
Installing DBD::mysql version 4.021...
Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'
Running make for C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.71)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v1.42)
```

and then a little further:

```
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4401)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.112150)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.68)

  CPAN.pm: Building C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
```

and these are the last few lines of output with the error.

```
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
inux-thread-multi/CORE"   dbdimp.c
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Skipping test because of notest pragma
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Comment: Are there any obvious errors in the output?  Does it fail when you're building it or when you're running the tests?  Are you using a CPAN client to install?

Comment: Here is the last lines of the output:
`Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Using DBI 1.52 (for perl 5.008008 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod

Comment: `cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
inux-thread-multi/CORE"   dbdimp.c
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.021.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Skipping test because of notest pragma
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible`

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, I didnt have enough characters.
I assume I am using a CPAN client to install due to this line in the output:
`CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4401)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.112150)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.68)`

Comment: Can you edit that info into your question?  And what is the command that you're running to do the install?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's a good idea to use the distribution's native package management tools whenever you can. Assuming you're using a distro that is based off RedHat Enterprise Linux 5 or 6 (such as CentOS or Scientific linux among others), you should be able to do:

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
```

(It's possible that there are reasons why you're not doing it this way; if there are, please tell us.)

If that completes successfully, then it's likely that your Bugzilla dependency will be satisfied.

Updating:

The version of the perl MySQL driver that is available in your yum repository is too old for Bugzilla, so there are 2 possible approaches:

- get a new repository such as http://iuscommunity.org/Repos. The trouble with this is that it will likely mean upgrades/conflicts with the other mysql packages such as your mysql-server package.
- get the perl MySQL driver some other way (ie build it yourself)

This is the easiest approach I can think of for the 2nd option. (As root, you might not need the --sudo). You **will** need to have development tools such as a compiler, make, etc. AND the mysql development package (mysql-devel) installed.

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
cpanm DBD::MySQL
```

If this is successful, bugzilla's dependency should be satisfied.

Comment: My only concern (and this is due to lack of experience) is that I have a number of live sites on this server and I am nervous of "breaking" the databases.

Will this in anyway affect the already installed mysql database?

Comment: This is the result...
`Setting up Install Process
Package perl-DBD-MySQL-3.0007-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

According to bugzilla, I need DBD-mysql (v4.001)

Comment: It is likely if you install the latest DBD::MySQL from CPAN (as above: yum install mysql-devel && cpanm DBD::MySQL), that everything will just work. If it doesn't, please post output, I'll help you debug. It is possible that DBD::MySQL v4+ requires newer mysql client libraries than you have available in which you will not be able to install bugzilla without either upgrading the current libraries (with the remote possibility of disturbing existing service) or installing both versions of the library. Fortunately, IUS makes this easy giving you 2 packages: yum install mysql55-libs mysqlclient16

Comment: This solution would work, however the version of linux that I had on my server did not support perl module mysql 4.001. I ended up killing my server as php was updated but the php compilers were not.

I have spent the past 4 days rebuilding a new server and moving all my data from the old server to the new one.

CAUTION: READ WHAT UPDATES DO TO YOUR SYSTEM... don't be a dummy like me!!

Thanks for all the help guys! if anything, I definitely learned a valuable (expensive) lesson from all this.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to make the DBD modules.  I end up just installing the packaged version from the repository.  In Debain flavors it's `libdbd-mysql-perl` but I think Red Hat has it listed as `perl-dbd-mysql`.